# google analytics api from desktop which method to use clientlogin, authsub, oauth

Tags: google-analytics

I have written a simple php program to fetch google analytics data. I did this to test how to authenticate and how to get data feeds. it is working well.

Actually my plan is to display a small window which will update with analytics data at certain time intervals. I will use .net to do so.

Currently i am using clientlogin method. authsub is meant for web apps and oauth seems to be tedious i guess.

Shall i be with clientlogin method or do i have to switch on to another.

With other methods we dont have to mention usename and passwords where as in clientlogin method we have to mention username and password.

Expecting suggestins, comments and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you planning on releasing this code as something that a user will use on their own computers, or is this an internal app for your own use?

If this is a tool that you'll be releasing, Google suggests using oAuth, so that you don't have to collect and pass any credentials. If this app is for your own use then you will be fine passing your username and account info the way you are now.

Comment: Initially i am going to use it for my own purpose. Thought of writing a c program in .net to do this which will popup with latest details. If i want to use it anywhere then it is good to write in oauth. isn't it?

Comment: It is. I think it would be good practice to use oAuth, considering it's adoption with systems like the Stack Exchange.